# Applying formatting from within tables

Tags: org-table

It seems that `^c ^c` applies table formatting only when 
point is on the formatting line (the one beginning
in `#+tblfm:`).  Is it possible to have `^c ^c` apply formatting
even when point is in the table itself?
Or is one supposed to do something else from within the table?
It's a bit laborious every time to have to place point at the formatting
line before pressing `^c ^c`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `#+tblfm:` line is for table formulas, not formatting.

Pressing <kbd>M-Q</kbd> anywhere on the table reformats the whole table, this is called *table-align*. The same happens when tabbing through cells, or when pressing <kbd>C-C C-C</kbd> anywhere on the table.

If, however, you want to recalculate all formulas (which is what happens when <kbd>C-C C-C</kbd> on the formula definitions), you can call <kbd>C-c *</kbd> and its variants.

References:

- [Table editor](https://orgmode.org/manual/Built_002din-Table-Editor.html)
- [Updating the table](https://orgmode.org/manual/Updating-the-table.html)